# Как настроить Server Push HTTP/2 на сервере Apache

Tags: apache2, http2

Заинтересовался я темой Server Push прочитал статейку https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/04/guide-http2-server-push/ .
Никак не могу понять как настроить пуш в .htaccess, вроде делаю все как в статье, пробовал прописывать разные пути к файлам, как полные, так и относительные (от html).

```
<FilesMatch "\.html$">
    Header set Link "</css/styles.css>; rel=preload; as=style"
<FilesMatch>
```

Читал другие ресурсы, но так  и не смог добиться заветной надписи "Push". Писал в поддержку хоста, они сказали что HTTP2 поддерживается.
Может вы сможете подсказать, что я делаю не так?

Comment: HTTP2 поддерживается, а Server Push может не поддерживается

Comment: Я к ним  обращался с этой проблемой, посоветовали изменить путь  к css. Думаю если бы Server Push не поддерживался они бы сказали.